# Apply Canny edge filter on raster failes with scikit-image

Tags: python, rasterio, scikit-image, edge-detection

I have raster with one band and I would like to do edge detection with Canny edge filter.

This is my raster:

[image]

I have opened it with rasterio and covert it into array :

```
img=srs.open("raster.tif")
array=img.read()
```

Then i'm trying to apply the Canny filter as following (based on this: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_canny.html):

```
# Compute the Canny filter for two values of sigma
edges1 = feature.canny(array)
edges2 = feature.canny(array,sigma=3)
```

but it fails with this error:

> **ValueError: The parameter `image` must be a 2-dimensional array**

I  read that this can happpen if my image is not in grey scale, but I have shown it as grey scale:

```
show((img,1),cmap='Greys_r')
```

so I tried to checl what is my array type:

```
type(array)
>>>numpy.ndarray
```

so I have no idea why I get this error message saying the image is not 2 dimensoinal as it is 1 band with X  and Y axis.

**My end goal - to be able to apply Canny edge on my image and to understand why I get this error**

Comment: @BERA (1302, 2115)

Comment: well I just used reshape in it worked, but I was afraid to loost the coordinates data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes an image "looks" gray, but actually has 3 color channels with the same red, green, and blue values. To check that your image is grayscale, check `array.shape` rather than `type(array)`. If it is `(X, Y, 3)`, then you have an RGB image. To convert, you can use `skimage.color.rgb2gray`, and then pass the result to `canny`.